# Issues Setting Up Airport Express to Extend Network

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have tried to set up my WLAN with the following topology:

- Cable modem providing Internet connectivity
- Airport Extreme as the primary access point
- Airport Express as a repeater (to extend my wireless coverage)

I follow the prompts from the AirPort Utility, and the Airport application even displays the Express properly. However, once completed, I lose **all** wireless connectivity to **all** devices. Only my CAT-5 wired devices stay online. A reboot of the Extreme solves nothing. Thus far, the only way to recover from this is to change the WPA password, and apply. I've done this several times, and have yet to successfully connect the Express to the network.

(NOTE: To clarify, the AirPort Express still shows up in the device scan, but every wireless device, from printer, to iPads, to MacBook Pro, no longer has connectivity to **ANY** wireless access point. I am never, at any point, able to connect to the Express, but after the initial configuration, I am not able to even connect to the Extreme; I am forced to change the WPA password in order to reconnect.)

I've followed the prompts completely, but apparently, I am missing something. Ideas?

Comment: You loose means? they do not show up in scan, you loose the repeater and primary ? please clarify

Comment: So noted in the OP.